# Cloud Functions onWrite ignore subnodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking for a option to ignore subnodes when listing `onWrite()` function.

I'm working on a ranking dashboard. On the first level is a total amount of points for each level. In the subnodes under each user, there are details from where the points are calculated.

I just want to notify the app users, about their total amount of points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to ignore child nodes when using onWrite(). Use denormalization to trigger the function on just the data you require. Check out these resources to find out more:

[YouTube - Denormalization is Normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&index=6&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

[Firebase Blog Post - Denormalizing your Data is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)